# Creating a method for returning elapsed time from (DateTime.Now)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, windows-8, time

I was making an instant messenger app, so i need a way to tell the user how long ago a message was received.  My method takes in a DateTime.Now that was captured and checks it against the current DateTime.Now to see elapsed time, it then calculates it and returns things like "6 seconds ago", "1 minute ago" , " 1 month ago".

I posted my code here:  http://pastebin.com/7N1kqLQ6

I dont believe my code is right. Does anyone else see a problem in my code logic?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal  thanx. I was looking for something like this.

Comment: You shouldn't ever use `DateTime.Now` for this anyway.  You will have errors around daylight saving time transitions.  [Read more here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeSpan.Minutes` is always going to be `< 60`, because it's only the "minutes component" not the "time represented in minutes."

You should probably be using the corresponding Total methods, such as `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`.